# How to get key-value of context in Django?

Tags: python, django

I try to query to get all of Topic of Post. Each Post belong multiple Topic. I got this but i don't know how to pass to Template. This is my code. In template i got posts but i can't access topics of single posts. Thank for help.

models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=121)
    content = models.TextField()
    published = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title



class Topic(models.Model):
    topic_name = models.CharField(primary_key=True,unique=True, max_length=60)
    posts = models.ManyToManyField(Post)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.topic_name
```

views.py

```
def codinglife(request):
    posts = Post.objects.filter(topic__topic_name__contains='codinglife') #Get posts belong topic 'codinglife'
    context = {
        'posts': Post.objects.filter(topic__topic_name__contains='codinglife')
    }
    # for each post get topic this post belong many topic 
    for post in posts:
        context[post.id] = Topic.objects.filter(posts=post)

    return render(request, 'site/topiclistview.html', context)
```

Template

```
{% extends "site/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
    {% for post in posts %}
        <article class="media content-section">
            <div class="media-body">
                <div class="article-metadata">
                    <small class="text-muted">{{ post.published }}</small>

                    {% comment 'need to show topic her' %}
                    {% endcomment %}

                </div>
                <h2><a class="article-title" href="#">{{ post.title }}</a></h2>
                <p class="article-content">{{ post.content }}</p>
            </div>
        </article>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to do anything special in your views (but see below though), you just have to [use the reverse relationship](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#many-to-many-relationships):

```
{% for post in posts %}
     <small class="text-muted">{{ post.published }}</small>
     <ul> 
       {% for topic in post.topic_set.all %}
       <li>{{ topic.name }}</li>
       {% endfor %}
     </ul>
      <h2><a class="article-title" href="#">{{ post.title }}</a></h2>
        <p class="article-content">{{ post.content }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Now this can optimized a bit by [using `select_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) in your view to avoid doing 1+N db queries.